# Why the Overly Complex and Cop Out Answers Sometimes?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe

So, I was just wondering if anyone could give me a succinct answer on why exactly it's better to code mostly in an AS3 file as opposed to most on the timeline?

I've heard a lot of people answer questions with a cop-out "don't put so much code in your timeline".  I've tried both ways and found some pros and cons on each, but it just seems silly to me for so many people to parrot the general good coding practice techniques.

Another thing about that is that a lot of times I'll be searching for help on coding, and people will give such complicated responses, and half the time I'll use little snippets of code as well as incorporate a small portion into my projects.  Also, the AS3 API site also gives waaaay overcomplicated coding examples.  Why do people do this?  I could figure out some of my issues much more quickly if people just simplified the code examples.

Comment: There's no **better** here. Each way has its own purpose, pros and cons. Timeline scripts are suitable for smaller projects, with minor logic and timeline navigation mostly. The thing is, as the project grows bigger the timeline scripts get out of hand very, **VERY** fast. You can handle 1 script, maybe 3-5, but 10? 20? 100? **AS3** classes, at the other hand, could seem unnecessary with the smaller projects, but they provide scalability and manageability. You can use dedicated IDEs with autocomplete, code parser, and all the other features which makes your developer's life immensily easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three good reasons not to put it on the timeline:

1. Your code will be stuck inside a binary file, not allowing you to use version control nor review changes to it.
2. You're going to hide code behind menus, making it hard to review in an instance. When it's all in one place you can easily refactor it, and change it.
3. By putting code on your timeline, you're making your code be dependent on the Animate compiler. (Animate is going to take your code and inject it into your document class using the undocumented function addFrameScript to make things work). The code isn't easy to migrate in this form, if you ever feel the need to re-code in another language.

Please use an IDE when coding. It will help prevent mistakes and even suggest ways to make your code simpler. (To name a few IDEs: FlashDevelop, VSCode, IntelliJ Idea Ultimate (paid).)

To clear up any confusion, writing code in an AS3 file instead of the timeline doesn't mean make things less organized or put code where it doesn't make sense to put it.
What you should be doing is creating a new AS3 file for every MovieClip that you need scripted, then going into the `Symbol Properties` of your movieclip and selecting `Export for ActionScript` and set the class name to your AS3 file. The runtime will automatically declare the instances in your file at compile time. What you can do is actually declare them yourself in the file, to have full completion capability in your IDE.

What I like doing is first setting the movieclip to export for actionscript, publishing my project, then opening the compiled swf using [Free Flash Decompiler](https://github.com/jindrapetrik/jpexs-decompiler/releases), and copy paste the generated class into a new AS3 file. (You'll want to only copy paste the class and generated instance variables.) Then you can code in your AS3 file with all the symbols contained within the MovieClip already referenced.

Comment: Well, I never really tried making an AS3 file for every movie clip.  I was just told that the warning that there is no script for the movie clip when you convert to a symbol was normal and you don't have to worry about it.  Screenshots would be helpful even if I'm not going to use it right away.  It would just be nice to have it for reference.

Comment: Timeline code is unacceptable to me. I don't make projects without version control. I suggest you teach yourself to use git if you plan on continuing programming. Having a way to review exactly what coding changes you made the past hour, or last night at 3 am is absolutely priceless. Even more so, being able to rollback your program to a particular time to test for the existence of a bug you're tracking.